# How to access entire row data in angular-ui-grid cellFilter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I would like to execute a cellFilter to programatically define what needs to be displayed within a cell.  When defining the column definitions you need to specify what field the cell corresponds with, however I need access to the entire row of data within the cellFilter, not just a single field.  Is it possible to pass multiple fields to a filter, or the entire row?

```
{
name: 'To',
field: 'myData',
cellFilter: 'formatCaller'
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Share what you've tried so far

Answer (score 8):

Yes, passing `this` as an argument to your filter sends the current scope

```
cellFilter: 'formatCaller:this`
```

Then in your filter you can access the row like so:

```
app.filter('formatCaller', function () {
  return function (value, scope) {
    return scope.row.entity.whateverField + ' ' + yourFormattingFunction(value);
  };
});
```

You can find a deeper explanation (and a plunker demo) here: http://brianhann.com/6-ways-to-take-control-of-how-your-ui-grid-data-is-displayed/ (caveat: I'm the author).

Comment: Quite a few on the code examples on that page are currently showing 'Not Found' or a blank frame.

Comment: @ColtMcCormack My apologies! Looks like there was http/https mixed content that was being blocked. All the plunker examples should be working now.

Comment: I had to use `scope.$parent.$parent.row.entity`.  Seems a little hacky, but I do have some grouping done in my grid though, not sure if that's why.