# Search text from cell template not working in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I have defined a conditional cell template for one of the column. Its displaying the data correctly but I am not able to search for the text in the cell template.
Here is my plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/TDX5jtPord1hkzCVaw3L?p=preview

```
var template1 = '<div class="">' + 
'<div class="" ng-if="COL_FIELD > 30">Greater </div> ' +
'<div class="" ng-if="COL_FIELD < 30"> Lesser </div> ' +
'</div>';
```

In the template I have put the condition that.. if COL_FIELD > 30 then then write Greater.. or else write Lesser. And now I should be able to search for the Greater or Lesser in Number column.

[image]

Comment: Where is COL_FIELD defined in the plnkr?

Comment: COL_FIELD comes with ui-grid.. this is actually the value of that column before rendering the cell template.

Comment: I added that template in the plunkr and it shows fine so I'm not understanding what your issue is. Where is the search bar? What are you expecting to see and what are you observing?

Comment: Its is displaying fine.. but search is not working in the column having custom template. For example, if I search for "greater" in number column, it is not displaying any result

Comment: You would need to update your plunkr. There is no search field in this one.

Comment: Oh..my bad..It was not saved anyhow.. I have saved it now.. can you please check now. https://plnkr.co/edit/TDX5jtPord1hkzCVaw3L?p=preview

Comment: You would need to have a custom filter to override the selection match. Have you read the docs? This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29378217/1615594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to add a property on your data like :

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
    data.map(function(item) {
        item.greaterLesser = item.amount > 30 ? 'Greater' : 'Lesser';
    });
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
});
```

and then instead of using the amount with a template, just bind on this property.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      width: 70
    }, {
      field: 'greaterLesser',
      name: 'Number',
      width: 90,
    }, {
      field: 'amount',
      name: 'Currency',
      cellFilter: 'currencyFilter:this',
    }]
};
```

Here is the [updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oGcJcvRRoQucWlPYg8B7?p=preview)

**Edit**

If you want to use the template, you could implement the search function yourself. You can add the `filter` option to your field and implement the `condition` function. Something like:

```
filter: {
    condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {
        var value = cellValue > 30 ? 'greater' : 'lesser';
        var result = value.search(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        return result > -1;
    }
}
```

Here I used the `search` function but you could use `match` or some other function.
Here is a [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BDBVujaCGBtZPPISxfQD?p=preview)

Comment: This serves the purpose for me now.. but there are few cases where I must need to define template.. because of specific styling and other things..So I wanted to search from that template. Anyway this works for me now. Will mark this answered if I dont get any more response.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to make search work

```
field: 'EmpId', 
displayName: 'Employee Type', 
cellTemplate: '<div style="cursor:pointer"  class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.appScope.GetEmployeeType(row)}}</div>', 
filter: {
            condition: function (searchTerm, cellValue,row,column) {
            var value = $scope.GetEmployeeType(row);//same function that you use to display value in cell Template
            return (value.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())>-1);
                            }
                        }
```